# Can't uninstall npm package spotifydl

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed `npm install -g spotifydl`, but the package is outdated and does not work. So then I tried uninstalling `npm uninstall -g spotifydl` it but all it does is reinstalling it, I tried uninstalling it via brew but didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `npm un -g spotifydl`?

Comment: Nope all it did is put the packages up to date

Comment: Are you able to uninstall other packages with npm? Or is it just a problem with spotifydl

Comment: Its just a problem with spotifydl the rest I can install and then uninstall

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling without the global flag? (`npm uninstall spotifydl`)

Comment: Yes I did it still gives me the update message

Comment: How about you use the --save flag? (`npm uninstall -g spotifydl --save`) or maybe even `npm uninstall -g spotifydl --save-dev`

Comment: This is what it gave me `up to date, audited 1 package in 1s` still giving me put to date message

Comment: Try updating your package.json with

```npm install -g npm-check-updates```
```ncu -u```
```npm update```

Comment: Or try checking if you already uninstalled the package with ```npm list -g```

Comment: Still gives me the same issue I think it downloaded somewhere else other than npm

Comment: Try using ```npm list -g``` too check if you did or not

Comment: great how did you resolve the problem?

Comment: I used `npm list -g` and found that the package renamed itself then I was able to uninstall it using `sudo uninstall -g spotify-dl`

Comment: great that you solved the problem!